# Shell Scripting to extract date

Tags: shell, logic

Need a logic in shell scripting where I give the start and end date,
say 
`startDate=20140101` & 
`endDate=20160130`

I should be able to extract `startDate_new=20140122` and `endDate_new=20140221` in first loop.

In next loop will need `startDate_new=20140222` and  `endDate_new=20140321` so on, till `startDate_new=20151221` & `endDate_new=20160122` and exit out. Can you provide any shell scripting logic that can be used to achieve this.

test.sh has,

```
startdate=2013-03-01
enddate=2013-04-30

curr="$startdate"
while true; do
    echo "$curr"
    [ "$curr" \< "$enddate" ] || break
    curr=$( date +%Y-%m-%d --date "$curr +1 day" )
done
```

the above code prints,

```
2013-03-01
2013-03-02
2013-03-03
2013-03-04
2013-03-05
2013-03-06
2013-03-07
2013-03-08
.
.
.
.
2013-04-30
```

Can you help me how to extract the range I mentioned above ?

Came up with a new logic,

```
startdate=2013-03-21
enddate=2014-05-30

curr="$startdate"
while true; do
    [ "$curr" \< "$enddate" ] || { echo "$curr"; break; }
    echo "$curr"
    curr=$( date +%Y-%m-%d --date "$curr +1 month" )
    end=$( date +%Y-%m-%d --date "$curr +1 month +1day" )
done
```

the above logic gives

```
2013-03-21
2013-04-21
2013-05-21
2013-06-21
2013-07-21
2013-08-21
2013-09-21
2013-10-21
2013-11-21
2013-12-21
2014-01-21
2014-02-21
2014-03-21
2014-04-21
2014-05-21
2014-06-21
```

Can you help with how to retrieve end date as 22nd of each month ?

Comment: Yes we probaply could, but you should first decide which shell to use and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50220154/edit) your question to show your own coding effort and tell where you got stuck with a [mcve] to get help on your issue. [SO] is not a script writing service.

Comment: While it is true that there are cross platform options for Bash and Powershell, in general unless you literally want your solution to be cross platform, you should probably pick the one that is appropriate for your OS. What OS are you doing this on?

Answer (score 0):

Make a function:

```
# Usage: drange startdate endate [ time_increment ]
drange () 
{ 
    curr="$( date +%Y-%m-%d --date $1)"
    enddate="$( date +%Y-%m-%d --date $2)"
    shift 2 
    inc="${*:-+1 day}"
    until [ "$curr" \> "$enddate" ]; do
        echo $curr
        curr=$( date +%Y-%m-%d --date "$curr $inc" )
    done
}
```

Run it like so:

```
drange 20140222 20140321
drange 20151221 20160122 +1 month
s=20151221 e=20160122 i="+1 month"
drange $((s + 1)) $e $i
```

Comment: Am trying to avoid hard coding the dates as shown above, I would like to pass  startdate & enddate, and want the logic to handle the 22nd to 21st range of dates automatically. Please advice